# What is IE=Edge in GCF used for?

Tags: internet-explorer, meta-tags, google-chrome-frame

The Google chrome frame [developer guide](http://goo.gl/GRNYi) says,

> The following complete example indicates usage of Google Chrome Frame for IE6 users, and otherwise passes the "Edge" parameter to later versions of IE:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=IE6">
```

What does "passing the EDGE parameter to later versions of IE" means?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN [Defining Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx#setmode)

> Document compatibility modes allow you to control the way Internet Explorer interprets and displays your webpage
>
> Specifying `IE=edge` instructs IE to use highest available engine for established and emerging industry standards.

For example in IE9 the highest version of the engine is 9 (likewise the highest version for IE8 is 8), but IE9 can also render a web page using the IE8, IE7 or IE5 engine (with all of their old bugs) and IE8 can also render pages as IE7 or IE5 did.

If you have a page that was designed for IE7 but a user is now using IE9 has the page breaks; rather than updating all the code to work with both engines one can add the `<meta>` tag speficying that IE9 use the IE7 engine.

The Chrome frame recommendation is recommending this to future proof the code against new releases of IE. By specifying *"use the latest version"* you are not limiting the page to a specific version of IE.

In the context of your question I don't think that using *Edge* is specific to the GCF, but rather an instruction to IE.

Comment: ChromeFrame is dead now, of course.

Answer (score 2):

It makes IE use the most up to date version of the rendering engine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: For example, If we take IE8 browser, what is the most up-to-date version of the rendering engine available?

Comment: It is whatever browser version you have, so IE8 in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
>
> Note  Edge mode is intended for testing purposes only; do not use it
>   in a production environment.